# Updated a class with a subclass and it isn't showing up in other classes

Tags: vb.net, web-services, visual-studio-2017

Language: VB.net in Visual Studio 2017
Framework: 4.7.2

I have a web service on an IIS server. I recently updated the controller class, details class, and model class by adding a subclass to the details class and adding the necessary functions and api code to the model and controller classes. The problem I am having is the model and controller class aren't seeing the added subclass in the details class. VS is giving an error that the class isn't defined and intellisense isn't seeing it either.

Things I've tried
Restarting vs...no go
Stopping the web site in IIS and restarting vs...no go
Removing and rebuilding the classes manually...no go

Created a test web service on local machine and added the exact files on the IIS server and there aren't any errors and things work fine. I don't know if this is a vs issue or if I am just overlooking something in the code.

All the other subclasses and functions show up except the ShowS class which was added later in time.

Details Class

```
Public Class Details
  Public Class SomeClass
    Public Property Property1
  End Class
  Public Class ShowS
    Public Property Property1
    Public Property Property2
  End Class
End Class
```

Model Class

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports webservice.Details

Public Class Model
  Public Function GetSomeClass() as SomeClass
    ...processing code here
  End Function
  Public Function GetShows() as ShowS ...ShowS isn't found by vs or intellisense
    ...processing code here
  End Function
End Class
```

Controller Class

```
Imports System 
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web.Http
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports webservice.Details
Imports webservice.Model

Public Class Controller
  Inherits ApiController

  <Route("api/mystuff/someclass")>
  <HttpGet>
  Public Function GetAllSomeClass() As IEnumeralble(Of SomeClass)
    Dim rtv as new webservice.Model
    return rtv.GetSomeClass
  End Function

  <Route("api/mystuff/shows")>
  <HttpGet>
  Public Function GetShows() as IEnumerable(Of ShowS) ...once again ShowS isn't being found in the details class
    Dim rtv as New webserive.Model
    Return rtv.GetShows ...isn't found in the Model class
  End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Can you confirm you have a project reference, and not a direct dll reference?

Comment: Yes. I have a project reference and not a direct dll reference. It only started giving the error after adding the subclass and related function and api call to the existing code.

Comment: Soo.. Why did you make it an inner class?

Comment: This is a web service so there is a controllers class and a models class. The details class can be combined with the model class but either way this shouldn't be happening.

Comment: Have you built the project since modifying the class?

Comment: Yes. Multiple times before and after reloading the project and stopping IIS.